# kubernetesのエラー文

Tags: kubernetes

kubernetesを導入しているgcpインスタンスの中で下記のようなマニフェストファイルを作成し、
pod作成コマンド `kubectl apply -f pod.yml` を実行しましたが、エラーが表示されます。

正常に起動させるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ**

```
unable to recognize "pod.yml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

mani:pod.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: nginx
    env: study
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx:1.17.2-alpine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーを読む限りkubectlの実行環境でkubeconfigファイルが作成されていないように見えるので、利用したいkubernetesクラスタにリクエストできていないように思います。

> kubernetesを導入しているgcpインスタンス

がGKEでクラスタで構築していることを指しているのであれば
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#generate_kubeconfig_entry
にあるように

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]
```

でkubeconfigファイルを作成できると思います。

もしkubeadmのようなツールでkubernetesクラスタを作成しているのであれば
https://kubernetes.io/ja/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/
にあるように

```
export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/.kubeconfig
```

のようにしてkubeadmなどが生成したkubeconfigファイルを利用すればよいと思います。